# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'param1')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm completely new to Next.js and still trying to wrap my head round it kinda! I have the backend (node/express/mysql) running on port 5000 while i fetch data to server the client side.

Here is app/page.js

```
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import ComponentPicker from "../components/ui/editor/ComponentPicker";
import Footer from "../components/ui/Footer";
import SiteHeader from "../components/ui/SiteHeader";

export default function Home({
  pageData, logo, site, mainMenu, footerMenu, apiUrl, info,
}) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>
          {pageData?.name || t("404 Not Found")} - {site?.param1}
        </title>
        <link rel="icon" href={`${apiUrl.param1}/public/${logo.param2}`} />
      </Head>
      <SiteHeader logo={logo} apiUrl={apiUrl} mainMenu={mainMenu} />
      {pageData?.content?.map((comp, index) => (
        <ComponentPicker
          key={String(index)}
          type={comp?.component}
          data={comp?.data}
          info={info}
        />
      ))}
      <Footer site={site} footerMenu={footerMenu} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const { data: pageData } = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:5000/pages/home"
  );
  const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/info");
  return {
    props: {
      pageData,
      logo: data?.logo,
      site: data?.site,
      apiUrl: data?.apiUrl,
      mainMenu: JSON.parse(data.mainMenu.param1),
      footerMenu: JSON.parse(data.footerMenu.param1),
      info: data,
    },
  };
}
```

app/[slug].js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import ComponentPicker from '../components/ui/editor/ComponentPicker';
import Footer from '../components/ui/Footer';
import SiteHeader from '../components/ui/SiteHeader';

export default function Page({
  pageData, logo, site, mainMenu, footerMenu, apiUrl, info
}) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>
          {pageData?.name || t('404 Not Found')}
          {' '}
          -
          {' '}
          {site?.param1}
        </title>
        <link rel="icon" href={`${apiUrl.param1}/public/${logo.param2}`} />
      </Head>
      <SiteHeader logo={logo} apiUrl={apiUrl} mainMenu={mainMenu} />
      {pageData?.content?.map((comp, index) => (
        <ComponentPicker
          key={String(index)}
          type={comp?.component}
          data={comp?.data}
          info={info}
        />
      ))}
      <Footer site={site} footerMenu={footerMenu} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { slug } = context.params;
  const { data: pageData } = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:5000/pages/${slug}`
  );
  const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/info");
  if (!pageData) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      pageData,
      logo: data?.logo,
      site: data?.site,
      apiUrl: data?.apiUrl,
      mainMenu: JSON.parse(data.mainMenu.param1),
      footerMenu: JSON.parse(data.footerMenu.param1),
      info: data
    }
  };
}
```

Below is the error printed in console:

```
- event compiled client and server successfully in 6.2s (1341 modules)
react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next
- error app\page.js (26:41) @ param1
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'param1')
    at Home (./app/page.js:44:41)
  24 |           {pageData?.name || t("404 Not Found")} - {site?.param1}
  25 |         </title>
> 26 |         <link rel="icon" href={`${apiUrl.param1}/public/${logo.param2}`} />
     |                                         ^
  27 |       </Head>
  28 |       <SiteHeader logo={logo} apiUrl={apiUrl} mainMenu={mainMenu} />
  29 |       {pageData?.content?.map((comp, index) => (
- wait compiling /favicon.ico/route (client and server)...
```

I can't really tell what am doing wrong here nor relate properly.